# Problem loading local files with webkit in python

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

Every time I need to load a local file using webkit in python I need to start with "file://" which I need to include in all files I am working with. How can I eliminate the need to do that? I want to load files like `webview.load_uri('file.html')` instead of `webview.load_uri('file://file.html')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. `webview.load_uri()` takes a string containing a URI. `'file.html'` isn't a URI, `'file://file.html'` is.

Comment: I just discovered that fact. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

webview.load_string() takes the text of an html file. you can load the file into a file object without the file:// and read it into the load_string function.